# How to connect eth2 private network with another machine!

Tags: go-ethereum, eth-2.0, beacon-chain, prysm

Actually I made my own PoS Ethereum testnet which is public!(It means I can make a transaction to my network from anywhere available Internet.)
However my testnet is working with only **ONE NODE** with 64 validators.

What I want to do now is connect another node to my testnet.

Here's my questions:

1. How can I make them **automatically connected** each other? I need to set static peer by amdin.addPeer() at the moment.
2. I do set **machine2's** all the setting same as **machine1** except pubkey, but **beacon-chain is not working on machine2**. What did I set wrong?

Here's my commands for **geth** and **beacon-chain**

**- geth for machine1**

```
./geth --port 30303 --networkid 142536 --http 
--http.api eth,net,web3,engine,admin --http.addr "0.0.0.0" 
--http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "" --http.vhosts "" 
--ws --ws.api eth,net,web3,engine,admin --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" 
--ws.port 8546 --authrpc.jwtsecret jwt.hex --datadir gethdata 
--syncmode full --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock $pubKey1
```

**- beacon-chain for machine1**

```
./beacon-chain --datadir beacondata --min-sync-peers 0 
--genesis-state genesis.ssz --bootstrap-node= 
--interop-eth1data-votes --chain-config-file config.yml 
--contract-deployment-block 0 --chain-id 142536 
--accept-terms-of-use --jwt-secret jwt.hex 
--suggested-fee-recipient $pubKey1 --minimum-peers-per-subnet 0 
--enable-debug-rpc-endpoints --execution-endpoint gethdata/geth.ipc
```

**- geth for machine2**

```
./geth --port 30304 --networkid 142536 --http 
--http.api eth,net,web3,engine,admin --http.addr "0.0.0.0" 
--http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain "" --http.vhosts "" 
--ws --ws.api eth,net,web3,engine,admin --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" 
--ws.port 8546 --authrpc.jwtsecret jwt.hex --datadir gethdata 
--syncmode full --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock $pubKey2
```

**- beacon-chain for machine2**

```
./beacon-chain --datadir beacondata --min-sync-peers 0 
--genesis-state genesis.ssz --bootstrap-node= 
--interop-eth1data-votes --chain-config-file config.yml 
--contract-deployment-block 0 --chain-id 142536 
--accept-terms-of-use --jwt-secret jwt.hex 
--suggested-fee-recipient $pubKey2 --minimum-peers-per-subnet 0 
--enable-debug-rpc-endpoints --execution-endpoint gethdata/geth.ipc
```

I set different port because each machine got private IP from same router.(I did port forwarding too.)
It's the error of **beacon-chain**
[image]

Comment: I am struggling to do the same as you.
can you post your config ? regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved! Thanks for your helps!!!
I add bootnodes option for geth client, and bootstrap-node option for beacon-chain.
Now every nodes are connected each other!

Comment: I will accept my answer soon.... sorry for that. I need to wait for 2 days to accept...